# Does redrawing a card reset the fatigue count?

Tags: hearthstone

The druid class has a card called [Malorne](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/12293-malorne), which when it dies, gets shuffled back into your deck.

Does drawing Malorne reset the fatigue damage if you've taken damage from fatigue the previous turn?

For example: You have Malorne on the field and you draw into fatigue taking 2 damage. Your opponent kills Malorne on their next turn so it goes into your deck. Now you draw Malorne. On your next draw (fatigue), would you take 1 damage or 3 damage?

Comment: Gang Up may cause this situation to occur as well.

Comment: @C-S Yeah the answer to the question states a bunch of other cards as well. The general concept is the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.

> Fatigue never resets, in examples of Malorne, Iron Juggernaut, Recycle, etc. you will still get accumulating fatigue when out of cards.

[Quote by Heathstone Community Manager Zeriyah](https://twitter.com/CM_Zeriyah/status/539899308145770496)